# Overriding Configuration Values in config.json file in Azure Web App in ASP.Net 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core

I have a ASP.Net 5 application where i have some configuration values stored in `config.json` file. my config.json file is something like this.

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "SiteEmailAddress": "some@email.com",
    "APIKey": "some_api_key"
  }
}
```

I am setting up the config.json file to use in `Startup.cs` file like this.

```
public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration;

public Startup(IApplicationEnvironment appEnv) {

    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
                .AddJsonFile("config.json")
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

And accessing the config settings like this..

```
var email = Startup.Configuration["AppSettings:SiteEmailAddress"];
```

Earlier in ASP.Net we can use the `Web.Config` file to store these Application Settings and override them in App Settings in Azure App Settings section and that works with out any issues. But how can i do the same thing in ASP.Net 5 app.

How can i override the configuration values in config.json file in the App Settings section in Azure.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add them as App Settings in Azure, just like you are used to.
For nested config values, use

```
AppSettings:SiteEmailAddress
```

Etc... (AppSettings here referring to what you used in your config.json, the similarity to Azure App Settings is coincidental)

AddEnvironmentVariables() like you have done is required for this to work.

Comment: Also called `appsettings.json` in .NET Core.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have appsettings.json, you could add another file appsettings.{Environment}.json, ie appsettings.Production.json. Only settings, defined in the production file would override settings in the appsettings.json.
Now, add the following to the constructor of Startup

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true);
```

Next, you should go to launchSettings.json where all servers are defined and update environment variable to Production. For example,

```
"web": {
  "commandName": "web",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "Hosting:Environment": "Production"
  }
```

Now deploy to azure.

Comment: Is there a way to not have to change the Hosting:Environment every time we deploy? Can we make this permanent?

Comment: you should define "profile" for each environment in launchSettings.json file. Each profile should have it's own "Hosting:Environment". ie for IIS Express => Development, for web => Production

Comment: I see. But how Azure know to pick the "web" profile? What if I'd like to have an "Azure Production" profile?

Comment: It's probably defined in the msbuild script in VS. You 'd need to lookup how to edit it.